# HP ProLiant DL360 G4p with 13.10 server has network issues

Tags: networking, server

I've just installed Ubuntu Server 13.10 x64 on my HP ProLiant DL360 G4p.

I've configured the two HDD as RAID1+0 and the installation is proceeded without problems *(except during the partitioning step, it was saying that the drive was busy [or something similar] and I've chosen "Ignore")*

Now the server is up and is configured on my NT intranet, the main problem is that the network adapter looks not completely working.

When I ping the server, I lose some packets before it starts reply, and during the ping some packet is lost.

The network adapter is: HP NC7782 Gigabit Server Adapter and the server has 2 of them on board.

Any help?

Comment: show us the output of ifconfig?

Answer (score 1):

The network adapter here is a Broadcom device. Can you quickly run [**the firmware update for the controller**](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3288142&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_98e2ac21f94f424f89418dbd23%257CswEnvOID%253D4004%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) and see if that resolves the issue?

Try that first before troubleshooting other levels of the stack. Cables, switch port, etc. are worth investigating, too.

Recall that the G4 series of HP ProLiant are 8-9 years-old... Keep that in mind as you invest time.

Comment: (FYI)Generally when asking for more information on a question it's best to do so in a comment rather than an answer.